# camel blueprint force usage of log4j

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse, blueprint

Has anyone been able to use camel-blueprint together with logback? It seems that there are dependencies in camel blueprint which forces you to use log4j even though the log4j dependencies are removed from the pom. After running the project it starts to download the slf4j-log4j12 and then then complains of multiple bindings because it finds both log4j and logback.

I did the same with a camel java project and it worked fine to switch to logback. Does camel-blueprint force you to use log4j as its logging implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Answer found via nabble forum in through discussion with the camel community. For more details go here:
http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/camel-blueprint-force-usage-of-log4j-td5772826.html#a5772852

Essentially there are certain dependencies in the maven plugin which uses log4j. For production in JBoss Fuse or Karaf, its Pax logging.